# How to convert LaTeX document with multiple files to markdown using pandoc

Tags: latex, pandoc

I am trying to convert LaTeX (arXiv files) to markdown (where math equations can be set off with `$`). I am trying to use pandoc for this, yet run into issues where in a single document may have multiple .tex files used to build it. How would I find the base .tex file with which to call pandoc?

I am also ok with using some other method to convert arXiv to [gfm](https://github.github.com/gfm/), although I still want some markdown-type method to offset math equations. Would it be better to use [LaTeXML](https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML) (based on [ar5iv](https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/)'s usage of it) to convert from latex to XML and then pandoc to convert from XML to markdown?

Comment: Have you considered using the ar5iv version instead of starting from the tex source?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - The issue is I would still like to have latex equations notated as needed. The html source can format equations in html properly, but I want something like `text text $my equation$ more text`

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz - would it be better to use [LaTeXML](https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML) to convert LaTeX to HTML and then pandoc to convert HTML to markdown?